# Getting an error "list index out of range" when executing tensorflow code

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I am trying to execute following code developed in tensorflow for GAN, but whenever I execute it I receive index error "list index out of range"

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import time

dataset = pd.read_csv('kagglecreditcard.csv')

is_Class0 = dataset['Class'] == 0

norm_set = dataset[is_Class0]
is_Class1 = dataset['Class'] == 1

test_set = dataset[is_Class1]
#test_labels = test_set.pop('Class')

DATA_SIZE = 5
# BATCH_SIZE = 50
# TEST_SIZE = 400
# LAYER_DENSITY = [500, 400, 300, 100, 31]
EPOCHS = 5
# noise_dim = 50


# Y_test = test_set.sample(TEST_SIZE)
# Y = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(Y_test).batch(BATCH_SIZE)


X_train = norm_set.sample(DATA_SIZE)
norm_targets = X_train.pop('Class')
X = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train.values)).batch(1)
target = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((norm_targets.values))

Y_train = test_set.sample(DATA_SIZE)
Y = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((Y_train.values))

two = []
one = []


def make_generator():
    inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(30,),name='myInput')
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation=tf.nn.softmax)(inputs)
    outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(30)(x)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

    return model


def make_discriminator():
    inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(30,))
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(40, activation=tf.nn.softmax)(inputs)
    outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)(x)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
    return model


# This method returns a helper function to compute cross entropy loss
cross_entropy = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

def discriminator_loss(real_output, fake_output):
    return tf.losses.binary_crossentropy(real_output, fake_output)


def generator_loss(ith_sample,fake_output):
    return tf.keras.losses.kullback_leibler_divergence(ith_sample,fake_output)



generator_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-4)
discriminator_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-4)

noise = tf.random.normal([1,30])

generator = make_generator()
discriminator = make_discriminator()

gen_out = generator(noise)
disc_out = discriminator(gen_out)


gen_loss = generator_loss(two[0],gen_out)
disc_loss = discriminator_loss(one[0],disc_out)




re_out = []
fk_out = []
gn_loss = []
dc_loss = []
gen_gradients = []
disc_gradients = []

def train_step(records):
    noise = tf.random.normal([1, 30])

    with tf.GradientTape() as gen_tape, tf.GradientTape() as disc_tape:
      generated_records = generator(noise, training=True)

      real_output = discriminator(records, training=True)
      fake_output = discriminator(generated_records, training=True)

      re_out.append(real_output)
      fk_out.append(fake_output)

      gen_loss = generator_loss(records,fake_output)
      disc_loss = discriminator_loss(real_output, fake_output)

      gn_loss.append(gen_loss)
      dc_loss.append(disc_loss)


    gradients_of_generator = gen_tape.gradient(tuple(gen_loss), generator.trainable_variables)
    gradients_of_discriminator = disc_tape.gradient(tuple(disc_loss), discriminator.trainable_variables)

    gen_gradients.append(gradients_of_generator)
    disc_gradients.append(gradients_of_discriminator)

    generator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients_of_generator, generator.trainable_variables))
    discriminator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients_of_discriminator, discriminator.trainable_variables))


def train(dataset, epochs):

   for epoch in range(epochs):
     start = time.time()


     for image_batch in dataset:
       train_step(image_batch)


     print ('Time for epoch {} is {} sec'.format(epoch + 1, time.time()-start))


train(X, 4)
```

But when I execute the code, I get an error:

[error in the generation of loss value; hence there won't be any gradient associated with it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFPSH.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please **re-read** [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as it would seem that you missed some crucial points the first time you read it, namely "***DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question*" (emphasis in the original). Please edit & update your question with the error message as text, including the full error trace).

Answer (score 0):

At this chunk of the code:

```
generator_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-4)
discriminator_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-4)

noise = tf.random.normal([1,30])

generator = make_generator()
discriminator = make_discriminator()

gen_out = generator(noise)
disc_out = discriminator(gen_out)

gen_loss = generator_loss(two[0],gen_out) # Here
disc_loss = discriminator_loss(one[0],disc_out)
```

You have `two[0]`, which is supposed to retrieve the first element of the array.

But the error is telling you that the array is empty, hence you won't be able to retrieve the first element, because there is no first.